# What does the NetJets "QS" stand for?

Tags: terminology

Every NetJets aircraft that I've seen has a tail number ending in QS. Knowing aircraft operators, I'm sure it stands for something, but I don't know what.

**What does the QS stand for in NetJets tail numbers?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "QS" first stood for quarter share, according to the [1998 issue of Flying](https://books.google.com/books?id=tURRT6QU1jIC&lpg=PA96&ots=qoMON7rF5o&dq=netjets%20quarter-share&pg=PA97#v=onepage&q=netjets%20quarter-share&f=false). Each aircraft will have multiple owners to help bring the cost down for the owner.

Comment: This directly contradicts the other answer, which is backed up by a source.

Comment: This is actually what I have always heard too, and have heard from many other pilots.  Perhaps there are two meanings, or perhaps the pilot community has come up with it themselves, but it is a commonly known "meaning" for it.

Comment: Or perhaps it had this meaning first and the other one was created later by the marketing team. :)

Comment: Turns out it did!  Knowing what to search for, I was able to find an earlier source.

Answer (score 3):

In the United States, tail numbers can be arbitrarily assigned, assuming it is available and formatted per [FAA requirements](http://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/aircraft_certification/aircraft_registry/forming_nnumber/).

NetJets uses QS to identify their planes. According to an [article in the May 2002 issue of *Flying* magazine](https://books.google.com/books?id=gu1u7T9Lr7AC&lpg=PA80&ots=5wYb2M3PO9&dq=netjets%20%22quality%20service%22&pg=PA81#v=onepage&q=netjets%20%22quality%20service%22&f=false), "QS represents Quality Service," (page 82).